# WPF Button - Specifying Template and Style together

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a button:

```
<Button x:Name="someButton"
    Template="{StaticResource aButtonTemplate}"                        
    Command="{Binding MyCommand}"
    Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle1}" >
```

Now, the **aButtonTemplate** looks like:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="aButtonTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Border Name="border" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="2">
            <ContentPresenter x:Name="content" />
        </Border>

        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter TargetName="border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
            </Trigger>            
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
```

Then I have the **ButtonStyle1**

```
<Style x:Key="ButtonStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Viewbox>
                        <Grid>
                            <Ellipse Stroke="#f2f2f0" StrokeThickness="3" Fill="red" Width="77" Height="77"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Viewbox>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Now the problem is, due to the line `Template="{StaticResource aButtonTemplate}"` the Style ButtonStyle1 is not getting applied. I am not seeing any Ellipse.

How can I get the **Style** to work along with the **Template**?

EDIT: As I am specifying the ControlTemplate again in the Style ButtonStyle1, is there a way to combine both the styles into ButtonStyle2 using BasedOn? How can I do it?

Comment: I think you want to move all of the ControlTemplate work into your Style template and least that's how I remember doing it over year ago.

Comment: I am using the style in some other places too...So in this case i wouldn't want to combine those two

Comment: A control can have only one Template. Pick one template and use it. Set it in the style or set it on the Button; doesn't matter. Pick one template and make that one do whatever you want done.

Comment: @sabz You can use Style "inheritance" to customize a base style. update: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13016932/how-to-create-a-style-based-on-default-style

Answer (score 1):

```
<Style x:Key="StyleButton2"
       TargetType="Button"
       BasedOn="{StaticResource StyleButton1}">
<Setter Property="Template"
        Value="{StaticResource aButtonTemplate}"/>
</Style>
```

Then use just this style on the Button instance.

Obviously, have both StyleButton1 and aButtonTemplate defined before this style(cause the use of StaticResource).

Comment: Thanks for your response. However, this does not work. The style with ellipse is not getting applied...

Comment: Can you please post how you used it?

Comment: <Style x:Key="CombinedButtonStyle"
       TargetType="Button"
       BasedOn="{StaticResource ButtonStyle1}">
        <Setter Property="Template"
        Value="{StaticResource aButtonTemplate}"/>
    </Style>

Comment: I meant on the instance of the button. Anyway I think I misunderstood you.
If you want to see the Ellipse, get that ControlTemplate outside and make it a resource(give it a key), and then reference it either by using a style that has it, or on the Button directly.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I get the Style to work along with the Template?

The are both being applied but the `Template` property that you set to `{StaticResource aButtonTemplate}` overrides the value of the `Template` property that the `Style` sets. Local values takes precedence over values set by style setters: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230(v=vs.110).aspx.

> EDIT: As I am specifying the ControlTemplate again in the Style ButtonStyle1, is there a way to combine both the styles into ButtonStyle2 using BasedOn? How can I do it?

You can base a `Style` on another `Style` but you *cannot* base a `ControlTemplate` on another `ControlTemplate`. A `ControlTemplate` must be defined as a whole:

[WPF: Is there a way to override part of a ControlTemplate without redefining the whole style?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41570096/wpf-is-there-a-way-to-override-part-of-a-controltemplate-without-redefining-the/41570242#41570242)