# WPF ListView - Resource and ItemContainerStyle

Tags: c#, wpf

Just a quick question. Can i use **ListView.Resources** and **ListView.ItemContainerStyle** at the same time. It seems only one of them is working if i use together..

```
<ListView.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding PAMStatus}" Value="ACTIVE">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="DimGray" />
            </DataTrigger>

        </Style.Triggers>
```

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It seems only one of them is working if i use together..

Yes, there can only be one style applied to the `ListViewItem`(s).

But you can "extend" a style by creating a new one that is based on the original one:

```
<ListView ...>
    <ListView.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="style" TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding PAMStatus}" Value="ACTIVE">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="DimGray" />
                </DataTrigger>

            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListView.Resources>
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource style}">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```

[How to create a style based on default style?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13016932/how-to-create-a-style-based-on-default-style)

Comment: Thank you.. Actually i just put <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" /> between <ListView.Resources> and <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}"> .  But your way is better. Thank you